# Woocommerce - Get product variant and write to media attachment details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get product attributes and write them to "title" in **Media Gallery** of images which linked to them.

Like a picture in a product named "*Poster A*" linked to variant "*Black*" and variant "*20x30*", the title title to write to **Media Gallery** is "*Poster A Black 20x30*"

And, this action does after adding new product.
How to do it?
Thanks.